# What is the most correct way to create bidirectional relationship in Memgraph using Cypher?

Tags: memgraphdb, opencypher

I tried to run the query

```
CREATE (p1:Person {name: 'Harry'}), (p2:Person {name: 'Anna'})
CREATE (p1)<-[r1:MARRIED_TO]->(p2)
RETURN r1;
```

and I got the error `Bidirectional relationship are not supported when creating an edge`.

I got the same error for

```
CREATE (p1:Person {name: 'Harry'}), (p2:Person {name: 'Anna'})
CREATE (p1)-[r:MARRIED_TO]-(p2)
RETURN r;
```

I also tried

```
CREATE (p1:Person {name: 'Harry'}), (p2:Person  {name: 'Anna'})
CREATE (p1)-[r:MARRIED_TO]->(p2)
CREATE (p1)<-[r:MARRIED_TO]-(p2)
RETURN r;
```

but then I got `Redeclaring variable: r.` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
CREATE (p1:Person {name: 'Harry'}), (p2:Person  {name: 'Anna'})
CREATE (p1)-[r1:MARRIED_TO]->(p2)
CREATE (p1)<-[r2:MARRIED_TO]-(p2)
RETURN r1,r2;
```

They are going to be two distinct edges. An edge cannot point in more than one direction.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to create 2 relationships in order to create "undirected" relationships (since there is no such thing). Instead, when you want to `MATCH` a relationship without caring about its directionality, simply specify a pattern without a direction, like `MATCH (p1)-[r1:MARRIED_TO]-(p2)`.

Comment: I assumed that when matching they might care, plus I read the question as about edge creation and not matching with a potential misunderstanding about how edge direction works

Comment: This is bad practice, as it is wasteful of storage, requires added complexity to maintain consistent bidirectional relationships, and pollutes visualizations with extraneous relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create "undirected" or "bidirectional" relationships, since all relationships have a single specific direction. But luckily you never have to, since you can just *search* for relationships without caring about their directionality.

For example, this will find all `MARRIED_TO` relationships between `p1` and `p2` without caring about the direction of the relationship:

```
MATCH (p1)-[r1:MARRIED_TO]-(p2)
...
```

Comment: I understand, but the issue is with visualization. People tend to look at the arrows :)

Comment: @TenTonBonton It would not be acceptable for large databases to use redundant relationships just to "improve" visualizations, due to the extra resource and complexity requirements. And duplicate relationships would actually make visualizations much too busy once you have a lot of data to display. It is simply not good practice to do what you advocate.